# Uneven number of observations for three between-subject groups

Tags: r

I am doing a between-subject analysis of three types of product packaging (survey data). The control condition is the black and white packaging, the first manipulation group is in green packaging and the second manipulation is in blue packaging.
I have the data from these three condition groups in separate data frames on R. After eliminating missing or faulty observations, I have an uneven number of observations (89 for the black and white, 89 for the blue, and 94 for the green).

I need the indpendent variable "QualityRating" of each condition group in a joint data frame to run my anova, but this does not work because I have uneven observations for the three columns in the joint data set.

Q1: Am I allowed to delete the extra 5 observations of the green manipulation at random to ensure I have equal observation number to the other three groups? Does this bias my result? What is the correct code to do this at random?

Q2: Additionally, I need to combine the observations of the blue and green together in a joint column and compare that mean to the black and white one with anova, as my hypothesis is that both colored manipulation are higher in perceived quality than the black and white. How do I do this correctly?

For Q2: The combining of the two manipulation variables is not working. I  get a column with all the observations together, with an additional column specifying for which group and a column with the data of the black and white that I want to compare to. When I run the Anova though, it always compares the two manipulations with each other, instead of their combined value with the black and white.